# Oracle Financials GL Import

Tags: oracle, api, interface, finance

I'm working on importing data from our application into Oracle Financials GL.

It seems simple with the GL_INTERFACE table, and many resources online, but I don't seem to understand it.

- [A powerpoint presentation](http://www.richardbyrom.com/download/presentations/glinterface.ppt)
- [An import API](http://oracle.anilpassi.com/gl-interface-api-to-import-journals-3.html)

I'm looking for a simple way to post a transaction of $X on a specific date, between 2 or more accounts. I'm terrified of incorrectly posting anything in the GL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find some suitable documentation at the [Oracle Integration Repository](http://irep.oracle.com/). From the site:

> The Oracle Integration Repository is a compilation of information about the numerous service endpoints exposed by the Oracle E-Business Suite of applications. It provides a complete catalog of Oracle E-Business Suite's business service interfaces. The tool lets users easily discover and deploy the appropriate business service interface for integration with any system, application, or business partner.

It does, however, require you to register an account (free). Once you're in, it should be found under the "Financials" category.